# Is it possible to populate grouped categories dynamically in the grouped-categories plugin using an array?

Tags: highcharts, categories

Is it possible to populate grouped categories dynamically in the grouped-categories plugin?
using an array and a for loop to populate

Answer (score 2):

Just populate them to variable, then pass that variable array to Highcharts configuration object.

Comment: Hi Pawel, I have a grouped stacked column chart like this : http://jsfiddle.net/p9ccakx6/ . I'm setting my x axis on the fly and just defining x axis type as category. What i really want to do is to be able to group x axis on the first level by "Stack" (Male, Female) and the second level by Apples, Oranges etc..

Comment: Sorry, grouped categories plugin requires to get categories in `xAxis.categories`. You need to preprocess your data, get categories and pass on as option to the axis.